# Tween.js not chaining properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, tween, tween.js, tweenjs

I'm trying to use tween.js to chain some animations, however I find it is not working properly.

```js
var car={position:{x:100}};

var tween1 = new TWEEN.Tween(car.position)
.to({x: 105}, 1000).onComplete(() => {console.log("done 1 second")}); 
var tween2 = new TWEEN.Tween(car.position)
.to({x: 110}, 1000).onComplete(() => {console.log("done 2 second")}); 
var tween3 = new TWEEN.Tween(car.position)
.to({x: 115}, 1000).onComplete(() => {console.log("done 3 second")}); 

tween1.chain(tween2).chain(tween3).start()

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(1);
},1000);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(2);
}, 2000);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(3);
}, 3000);

function animate() {
TWEEN.update();
window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/18.6.4/tween.umd.js"></script>
```

And for each of the 3 tweens to take exactly 1 second. But somehow the library is merging tweens after the first....

http://jsfiddle.net/6gfkenw2/

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No [tween.js](/questions/tagged/tween.js) expert here, but it seems like you need to chain `tween3` to `tween2` before chaining that to `tween1`

---

So instead off

```
tween1.chain(tween2).chain(tween3).start()
```

Use

```
tween1.chain(tween2.chain(tween3)).start()
```

So the output becomes

```
1
done 1 second
2
done 2 second
3
done 3 second
```

---

```js
var car={position:{x:100}};

var tween1 = new TWEEN.Tween(car.position)
.to({x: 105}, 1000).onComplete(() => {console.log("done 1 second")}); 
var tween2 = new TWEEN.Tween(car.position)
.to({x: 110}, 1000).onComplete(() => {console.log("done 2 second")}); 
var tween3 = new TWEEN.Tween(car.position)
.to({x: 115}, 1000).onComplete(() => {console.log("done 3 second")}); 

tween1.chain(tween2.chain(tween3)).start()

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(1);
},1000);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(2);
}, 2000);
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(3);
}, 3000);

function animate() {
TWEEN.update();
window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/18.6.4/tween.umd.js"></script>
```